# Why jgGrid alway move new row to last row of last page after paging, sorting, filtering?

Tags: jqgrid

Why jgGrid alway insert new row as last row of last page after paging, sorting, filter?

I use datatype: local.
Add row method:

```
var records = g.getGridParam("records") + 1;
var addedIndex = Date.now();
g.addRowData(records , { }, 'first');

//var addedRecordIndexes = g.getGridParam('addedRecordIndexes');
//addedRecordIndexes.push(addedIndex);

g.editRow(records , true, function () {});
```

But after paging, sorting, filtering, new inserted row is alway move to last row of last page. I try to use 
`g.addRowData(1, {}, 'first')` but no luck.

**Why is this bug serious?**
This will make user confuse if they insert new row, then change to another page, then back. Oops, where is my new row?
*But actually, it's in last page at last row.*

Comment: If anybody need more information, please ask it here. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't full understand what you do. It's unclear where and when the code fragment which you posted will be executed. It's unclear why you use `addRowData` and `editRow` instead of usage [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow). The most important is: why the grid will be resorted and why the new added row should be always on the current page? What should be done is you use grid with 5 rows per page and the user will add more as 5 new rows? In general you can customize sorting by usage of `sorttype` defined as function.

Comment: Sorry for the later reply. The code above is called inside a custom button "Add New Row" on pager. I want to manipulate grid local totally. So I add "Add New Button" for custom handling.

About the `addRowData and `editRow, I want to add a row, then that row is turned on as edit mode, so user can start to work with it immediately.

Finally, about sorting, after I enter value to a row, the data isn't committed to server yet. I have to handle other cases, so I have a save button. The point is that, at this time, after entering value in to new row, data is local and then user start to sort. Gone!

Comment: It's still unclear what you do. Your problem was about *sorting*. By which column you sort? How the column is defined in `colModel`? Why new rows should be stay on the current page is the data from the corresponding column corresponds to the next page? **After saving of the row the grid will be not sorted**. So your code (which you don't posted) do this.